Angular routes not hitting first possible route
When I route to localhost:4200 I expect my route to redirect to localhost:4200/tabs/search as that is my starting route but somehow it stays at the route localhost:4200 and loads MyEventsComponent.
Here is my routes:
App.routes.ts
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/search',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsModule)
  },
];

tabs.routes.ts
export const tabsRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'search',
                loadChildren: () => import('../search/search.module').then(m => m.SearchModule),
            },
            {
                path: 'myevents',
                loadChildren: () => import('../myevents/my-events.module').then(m => m.MyEventsModule),
            },
            {
                path: 'settings',
                loadChildren: () => import('../settings/settings.module').then(m => m.SettingsModule),
            },
            {
                path: 'friends',
                loadChildren: () => import('../friends/friends.module').then(m => m.FriendsModule),
            },
            {
                path: 'shared',
                loadChildren: () => import('../shared/shared.module').then(m => m.SharedModule),
            },
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/tabs/search',
                pathMatch: 'full',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/search',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
];

And here is my search.routes.ts
export const searchRoutes: Routes = [      
  {
    path: '',
    component: SearchComponent,
  },
];

and the last one myevents.routes.ts:
export const myEventRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MyEventsComponent,
    },
];

Since my first route in app.routes.ts has a redirect to /tabs/search i expect it to enter my search.routes.ts and match with the default route there and render SearchComponent.ts but it doesn't. It stays as localhost:4200 and renders MyEventsComponent.
Thanks in advance!
I have tried different setups with my routes but I still get the error

Try changing the lazy loaded route, default navigation to just search.
We are already inside tabs, so we just need to navigate to search route.
export const tabsRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            ...
            { 
                 path: '',
                 redirectTo: 'search', // <- changed here
                 pathMatch: 'full',
            },
        ],
        ...

